# Petition for Open Access to Taxpayer-Funded Research

Tags: discussion

Probably most have heard about this, but just in case someone has missed it, here is [a short post](https://plus.google.com/u/0/103703080789076472131/posts/DDA6tr8SDJ8) and [a longer post](http://poynder.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/open-access-peoples-petition.html).

The petition itself is [here](https://wwws.whitehouse.gov/petitions#!/petition/require-free-access-over-internet-scientific-journal-articles-arising-taxpayer-funded-research/wDX82FLQ). You may want to check [the Access2Research site](http://access2research.org/) and [the Wikipedia article about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access2Research).

Edit:

Here is a post on [Tim Gowers' blog](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/have-you-signed-the-open-access-petition/) and an article in [The Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/science/blog/2012/may/22/us-petition-open-access-publishing?fb=optOut). You don't need to be a US citizen to sign the petition and its effects will not be restricted to the US.

It can be considered politics but it is an issue deeply related to the community. This post was intended to spread the information so others can also have a look at the petition and sign it in case they agree with it. It is not intended for discussion, arguing, nor convincing other about it. Blog posts like Gowers' are more appropriate for discussion.

Comment: This is politics, no? And US-centric?

Comment: Actually in the email (from the cost of knowledge) I received it explicitly said that non-US citizens could also sign the petition. However, yes it is politics. Vote to close?

Comment: Please do not abuse meta as a place for posting ads.

Comment: I think this issue is important enough to the community to warrant an exception. While following the site rules is important, they may not be applicable to every situation.

Comment: @Sid: I do not think that this is important enough to warrant an exception, but more importantly, what worries me most is that Kaveh does not seem to be aware that this is an ad and an abuse of meta. As you said, some exceptions are permissible, but first he should be aware that if this is allowed, it is an exception.

Comment: I do not believe that this issue warrants an exception to the rules.  It has been debated all over the Press and scientific media, let alone the Internet.  There is no need for stackexchange to join the fray.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, I personally don't see much difference between this and other similar information posts  on the meta about issues related/of possible interest to the community (e.g. advertising other stackexchange sites). I guess you also would say they are also "abusing" meta.

Comment: They are at least related to Stack Exchange, although they are also ads.  But yours are more similar to posting an ad about a conference in TCS on meta in that the only justification is that the ad is about something possibly of interest to people working in TCS.  If people start posting ads about conferences in TCS on meta, I am pretty sure I will stop checking meta.  Yours are coming very close to it.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, I see, I got your point. I guess it would have been more appropriate if I had posted this as an answer to the [community promotion ads](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/community-promotion-ads-2012) post. Will take more care next time.

Comment: @Kaveh: Maybe.  But as a separate issue, some people do not like politics on cstheory.stackexchange.com, so please be careful.  Also, chat might be an option as a place for ads which are not directly related to Stack Exchange, although there is probably no consensus on which topic is allowed in chat yet.